# How to add a key value into pair in existing local storage object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a key value pair into an existing localstorage object, below is what the object looks like:

```
category: [{"category_id":1,"name":"Default Category","position":1},{"category_id":2,"name":"Tech","position":1}]
```

I am trying to add `"level: 2"` in this existing object so it will look like

```
category: [{"category_id":1,"name":"Default Category","position":1,"level":1},{"category_id":2,"name":"Tech","position":2,"level":2}]
```

Is their any way it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each object in the array and simply add whatever you want.

```js
let arr = [{
  "category_id": 1,
  "name": "Default Category",
  "position": 1
}, {
  "category_id": 2,
  "name": "Tech",
  "position": 1
}];
var levelCount = 1;
for (let el of arr) {
  el.level = levelCount;
  levelCount++;
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, i will check code & update

Comment: 'el' is defined but never used

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate each object & assign new key, value for it.

```
var i = 1;
$.each(categoryArray, function (key, item) {
    item.level = i;    
    i++;
});
```

Now your categoryArray will have new assignment

Comment: Thankyou for your response, i will check code & update

Comment: I consider categoryArray as [{"category_id":1,"name":"Default Category","position":1},{"category_id":2,"name":"Tech","position":1}]
And don't understand what is not working here?