# How to get a specific object from whole object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get specific object from a whole object below is the example
by using `localStorage.getItem('shop/elasticCache/shirt');`
I get below data

```
{"description":"Tech Shirt","configurable_options":[{"attribute_id":80,"values":[{"value_index":"5176","label":"RUST"}],"label":"Color","attribute_code":"color"},{"attribute_id":125,"values":[{"value_index":"2898","label":"Small"},{"value_index":"2901","label":"Medium"},{"value_index":"2904","label":"Large"}],"label":"Size","attribute_code":"size"}],"tsk":1594790209,"size_options":[2898,2901,2904],"regular_price":28,"final_price":null,"price":28,"color_options":[5176],"special_from_date":null,"id":250659,"category":[{"category_id":2,"name":"Default Category","position":1},{"category_id":3,"name":"Clothing","position":14985},{"category_id":30,"name":"Bottoms","position":798},{"category_id":58,"name":"Leggings","position":1},{"category_id":1130,"name":"Char Test Category","position":30}],"sku":"S155551","product_links":[{"link_type":"related","linked_product_sku":null,"linked_product_type":null,"position":0,"sku":"P100031"},{"link_type":"related","linked_product_sku":null,"linked_product_type":null,"position":0,"sku":"P100031"}
```

I am trying to get

```
{"category_id":3,"name":"Clothing","position":14985},{"category_id":30,"name":"Bottoms","position":798},{"category_id":58,"name":"Leggings","position":1},{"category_id":1130,"name":"Char Test Category","position":30}]
```

Is their any way it can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

const {category} =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shop/elasticCache/shirt');)

or

```
const {category } =  {
    "description": "Tech Shirt",
    "configurable_options": [{
        "attribute_id": 80,
        "values": [{
            "value_index": "5176",
            "label": "RUST"
        }],
        "label": "Color",
        "attribute_code": "color"
    }, {
        "attribute_id": 125,
        "values": [{
            "value_index": "2898",
            "label": "Small"
        }, {
            "value_index": "2901",
            "label": "Medium"
        }, {
            "value_index": "2904",
            "label": "Large"
        }],
        "label": "Size",
        "attribute_code": "size"
    }],
    "tsk": 1594790209,
    "size_options": [2898, 2901, 2904],
    "regular_price": 28,
    "final_price": null,
    "price": 28,
    "color_options": [5176],
    "special_from_date": null,
    "id": 250659,
    "category": [{
        "category_id": 2,
        "name": "Default Category",
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "category_id": 3,
        "name": "Clothing",
        "position": 14985
    }, {
        "category_id": 30,
        "name": "Bottoms",
        "position": 798
    }, {
        "category_id": 58,
        "name": "Leggings",
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "category_id": 1130,
        "name": "Char Test Category",
        "position": 30
    }],
    "sku": "S155551",
    "product_links": [{
                "link_type": "related",
                "linked_product_sku": null,
                "linked_product_type": null,
                "position": 0,
                "sku": "P100031"
            }, {
                "link_type": "related",
                "linked_product_sku": null,
                "linked_product_type": null,
                "position": 0,
                "sku": "P100031"
            }]



            }
```

Comment: This also returns `{ "category_id": 2, "name": "Default Category", "position": 1 }`, so it should probably be `const category = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shop/elasticCache/shirt')).category.slice(1);`

Comment: i have console.log, but its undefined

Comment: Above code will give you the category array as response . What is your requirement only first element you want ?

Comment: Can i set some key value in the data of "const {category}" ?

Comment: i have marked you answer as right for the question.

Comment: Yes you can it will create a constant variable category

Comment: Please check whether you have value inside the Localstorage

Comment: i want to append it take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202196/how-to-add-a-key-value-into-pair-in-existing-local-storage-object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219028/discussion-between-hamendra-sunthwal-and-rahul-cv).

Comment: category.forEach((item,index)=>{ item.level=index})

Answer (score 0):

```js
objc={"description":"Tech Shirt","configurable_options":
[{"attribute_id":80,"values":[{"value_index":"5176","label":"RUST"}],
"label":"Color","attribute_code":"color"},
{"attribute_id":125,"values":[{"value_index":"2898","label":"Small"}
,{"value_index":"2901","label":"Medium"},
{"value_index":"2904","label":"Large"}],
"label":"Size","attribute_code":"size"}],
"tsk":1594790209,"size_options":[2898,2901,2904]
,"regular_price":28,"final_price":null,"price":28,
"color_options":[5176],"special_from_date":null,"id":250659,
"category":[{"category_id":2,"name":"Default Category","position":1},
{"category_id":3,"name":"Clothing","position":14985},
{"category_id":30,"name":"Bottoms","position":798},
{"category_id":58,"name":"Leggings","position":1},
{"category_id":1130,"name":"Char Test Category","position":30}],
"sku":"S155551","product_links":
[{"link_type":"related","linked_product_sku":null,"linked_product_type":null,"position":0,"sku":"P100031"},
{"link_type":"related","linked_product_sku":null,"linked_product_type":null,"position":0,"sku":"P100031"}]
}

res = objc["category"]
res.shift()
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

$(document).ready(function () {
var jsonObj = {
"description": "Tech Shirt",
"configurable_options": [{
"attribute_id": 80,
"values": [{
"value_index": "5176",
"label": "RUST"
}],
"label": "Color",
"attribute_code": "color"
}, {
"attribute_id": 125,
"values": [{
"value_index": "2898",
"label": "Small"
}, {
"value_index": "2901",
"label": "Medium"
}, {
"value_index": "2904",
"label": "Large"
}],
"label": "Size",
"attribute_code": "size"
}],
"tsk": 1594790209,
"size_options": [2898, 2901, 2904],
"regular_price": 28,
"final_price": null,
"price": 28,
"color_options": [5176],
"special_from_date": null,
"id": 250659,
"category": [{
"category_id": 2,
"name": "Default Category",
"position": 1
}, {
"category_id": 3,
"name": "Clothing",
"position": 14985
}, {
"category_id": 30,
"name": "Bottoms",
"position": 798
}, {
"category_id": 58,
"name": "Leggings",
"position": 1
}, {
"category_id": 1130,
"name": "Char Test Category",
"position": 30
}],
"sku": "S155551",
"product_links": [{
"link_type": "related",
"linked_product_sku": null,
"linked_product_type": null,
"position": 0,
"sku": "P100031"
}, {
"link_type": "related",
"linked_product_sku": null,
"linked_product_type": null,
"position": 0,
"sku": "P100031"
}]

```
            };
            for(var i = 1; i < jsonObj.category.length; i++){
                console.log(jsonObj.category[i]);
            }
        });
```

You can iterate through the entire object and can get the required values. The above code gives the values of category from index 1.